# Add links within a foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a loop which displays the tags, I'd like to add an anchor link to those tags. My code is as follows:

```
<?php $brands = get_the_tags(); ?>
<p class="brand-tags">
     <?php 
         $count = 0;
            foreach ($brands as $brand) {
                // echo sizeof($brands);
                if ($count < sizeof($brands)-1) {
                    echo $brand->name.', ';
                    $count += 1;    
                 }  
                else {
                     echo $brand->name;
                 }                          
            } 
     ?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$brands = get_the_tags(); 
$links  = array();
foreach($brands as $_brand){
    $links[] = '<a href="'.$_brand->url.'">'.$_brand->name.'</a>';
}
echo join(', ', $links);
```

Comment: Really `$_brand` and not only `$brand` in foreach, because you use `$brand` in loop body?

Comment: You can use it $_brand OR $_brand, its only refernce

Comment: But then you must use `$_brand` in loop body too.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to add link to brand name? Here is the code for that:

```
<?php $brands = get_the_tags(); ?>
                <p class="brand-tags"><?php 
                    $count = 0;


                    foreach ($brands as $brand) {
                        // echo sizeof($brands);
                    if ($count < sizeof($brands)-1) {
                        echo '<a href="add_link_here">'.$brand->name.' </a> ';

                        $count += 1;    
                    }   else {
                        echo '<a href="add_link_here">'.$brand->name.' </a> ';
                    }                           

                } ?></p>
```